# Error in Generics code

Tags: java, generics

Why is the below code giving a compile time error.

```
    Map<String,? extends Object> inputMap = 
                 new HashMap<String, ? extends Object>();
```

The compile time error.

> Cannot instantiate the type `HashMap<String,? extends Object>`

I want a map with String as key and which takes any object as value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?` does not mean "takes any object".  It means "take a specific type of object, that happens to be unknown", which doesn't make sense when actually creating a container.

Try this instead:

```
 Map<String,Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because you need to *specify* the type of the values that the `HashMap` should contain. Basically, you can't use a wildcard when instantiating a class.

This works fine though:

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> inputMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

However, saying that `?` should extend `Object` is kind of redundant, since everything extends object (you may of course have had something else than `Object` in your real code).

Comment: If you do this, though, you can never put anything in your map (as the only reference to it is a wildcard generic).

Comment: That's true. I was just trying to illustrate that it is the instantiation that actually requires concrete type parameters.